# Pls Help me Draw Google Chart Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I have a one question. google chart not draw.
I checked the php code and the script without the php code , it's ok. But when I put them together, google chart not draw. My English not good. Sorry.
[php code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMl4I.png)

[script result

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Month', 'Bán ra', 'Đơn hàng'],
            <?php 
            $d=getdate();
            $year=$d['year'];
            for ($i=1; $i <= 12 ; $i++) 
            {   
                $list_orrders = $this->transaction_model->order_follow_month($year, $i);
                $sum = 0;
                foreach ($list_orrders as $row_orrder) 
                {
                    $sum = $this->order_model->get_sum('qty',array('cart_id'=>$row_orrder->id));

                }
                if($i >= 1 && $i <=9)
                {
                    echo "['0".$i.'/'.$year."',".$sum.",".count($list_orrders)."],";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "['".$i.'/'.$year."',".$sum.",".count($list_orrders)."],";
                }
            }
             ?>
            ]);

        var options = {
          chart: {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses',
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      }
    </script>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBTVj.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `<?php` is not interpreted and your `$this->transaction_model->order_follow_month($year, $i);` and `$this->order_model->get_sum('qty',array('cart_id'=>$row_orrder->id));` comes from nowhere here.

Comment: I changed $row_orrder->id to $row_order['id']. And you suggested to me, I have not add $this->load->model. Now Everything is ok